# How can I apply different style on onclick input type button?

Tags: html, css

I am using a HTML input type button, it has gradient background color and vise versa on hover but I want on-click there should be solid background color and if I release button then it show as normal state.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    <input type="button" class="button_example" href="#" value="PREVIEW BUTTON"></input>

.button_example:active{
  background:#000;
}
```

[http://jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/robini/edit?html,css,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

So while you're holding the mouse button down you want it to change styling and then when you release it goes back to normal? There's a `mousedown` and `mouseup` event in jQuery you can use.

Basic structure:

```
("#element").mousedown(function(){
    this.css();
});

("#element").mouseup(function(){
    this.css();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below css to your button.

```
<button type="button" class="myBtn">Highlight me when Clicked</button>
.myBtn:active {
    background-color: #dd4814;

}
```

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cfymbLw1/). Change css as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks, Its help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="buttonId" value="Button" onclick="showChanges()"/>
```

and JS:

```
<script>
function showChanges(){
    document.getElementById("buttonId").style.backgroundColor ="red";
}
</script>
```